# title string except for roman numbers

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a DF like this:

| ID | Model |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | POWER JET III |
| 2 | ADI MAX VI |

I need to capitalize each word so I´m doing :

```
DF['Model']=DF['Model'].str.title()
```

but the problem is the roman numbers. I m getting:

| ID | Model |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Power Jet Iii |
| 2 | Adi Max Vi |

How could I get the same but mantaining roman numbers?

Comment: Can you come up with a rule that tells you whether a word is a roman number or not? Why is this question tagged `regex`? As an aside, the `string` standard library module is largely unnecessary nowadays - in particular, `string.capwords` can be replaced with the `title` method of the string.

Comment: You have two choices: Convert the entire string to titles as you're doing now and then re-capitalize the roman numerals, or omit the roman numerals from the titles conversion.  Of course both ways require you to know what is a roman numeral and what isn't.

Answer (score 0):

Could you perhaps only use [`str.title`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.title) on every word but the last one:

```
In [1]: import pandas as pd
   ...: 
   ...: d = {'ID': [1, 2], 'Model': ['POWER JET III', 'ADI MAX VI']}
   ...: df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
   ...: df
Out[1]: 
   ID          Model
0   1  POWER JET III
1   2     ADI MAX VI
In [2]: df['Model'] = df['Model'].str.split().apply(lambda xs: ' '.join(
   ...:     s.title() if i != len(xs) - 1 else s for i, s in enumerate(xs)))
In [3]: df
Out[3]: 
   ID          Model
0   1  Power Jet III
1   2     Adi Max VI
```

If it is not guaranteed that the roman numeral will be at the end, you can use:

```
df['Model'] = df['Model'].str.split().apply(lambda xs: ' '.join(s.title() if not is_roman_numeral(s) else s for s in xs))
```

Where `is_roman_numeral` is some function that returns if a string is a roman numeral or not.